# Spacing elements in javascript marquee, using php loop for elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a javascript marquee, and it's actually working fine except:

I'm using a php loop (working perfectly) to get each element of content that scrolls through the marquee.

The content is correct and the duration is fine, but my elements are right next to one another and I'm trying to put plenty of space between.

Right now it looks like `element 1element2` but I"m looking for more of

```
element 1                                              element 2
```

PHP/HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <?php foreach($tickerContent as $tContent):?>
    <div class="marquee"><h2><?php echo $tContent['content']?></h2>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.marquee').marquee({
    duration: 30000,
    gap:40,
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just add margin between the elements in the CSS styling?

Comment: I just didn't know if there was a more appropriate way with JS (i've never actually used marquee in JS) but yeah, that makes sense as well

Comment: You can now do tickers (marquees) without js: https://codepen.io/lewismcarey/post/pure-horizontal-css-ticker

Comment: There might be an extra option you can add to the `.marquee()` call, but since I don't use JQuery, you'll have to consult the api. And for the record, CSS animation + keyframes can be used to create a marquee completely in CSS. So if you don't want to use JS for the marquee, CSS is an option as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee, you must set ***duplicated*** to **true**

> **gap** Gap in pixels between the tickers. Will work only when the duplicated option is set to true. Default: 20. Note: 20 means 20px so
>   no need to use '20px' as the value.